# Image is not posting through form post method

Tags: php

I am beginner in codeignitor.I want to post an image through a post method. All data is being posted but the image is not posting in controller.

Here is my view code.

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('adminpanel/add_event');?>" method="post" name="addform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <fieldset>

    <p>
      <label style="width:20%;float:left;">Event Title<span style="color:red">*</span>
      </label>
      <label style="width:1%;float:left;">:</label>
      <input class="text-input small-input" type="text" name="event_title" id="event_title" placeholder="Event Title" value="<?php if(isset($teenzstore_edit_data['product_name'])) echo $teenzstore_edit_data['product_name'];?>" />
    </p>
    <p style="clear:both;"></p>
    <p>
      <label style="width:20%;float:left;">Select Age<span style="color:red">*</span>
      </label>
      <label style="width:1%;float:left;">:</label>
      <select name="age" id="age" class="form-control" class="form-control" onChange="return get_product_filter('<?php echo base_url();?>',this.value);">
        <option value="0">Select Age</option>
        <option value="12">12</option>
        <option value="13">13</option>
        <option value="14">14</option>
        <option value="15">15</option>
      </select>
    </p>
    <p style="clear:both;"></p>
    <p>
      <label style="width:20%;float:left;">Event Image</label>
      <label style="width:1%;float:left;">:</label>
      <input type="file" name="event_image" id="event_image" onchange="checkExtension(this.value)" />
    </p>
    <p style="clear:both;"></p>
    <p>
      <label style="width:20%;float:left;">Event Date<span style="color:red">*</span>
      </label>
      <label style="width:1%;float:left;">:</label>
      <input class="text-input small-input" type="text" name="event_date" id="event_date" placeholder="Event Date" value="<?php if(isset($teenzstore_edit_data['product_points'])) echo $teenzstore_edit_data['product_points'];?>" />
    </p>
    <p style="clear:both;"></p>

    <p>
      <label style="width:20%;float:left;">Event Time<span style="color:red">*</span>
      </label>
      <label style="width:1%;float:left;">:</label>
      <input class="text-input small-input" type="text" name="event_time" id="event_time" placeholder="Event Time" value="<?php if(isset($teenzstore_edit_data['product_points'])) echo $teenzstore_edit_data['product_points'];?>" />
    </p>
    <p style="clear:both;"></p>
    <p>
      <label style="width:20%;float:left;">Event Venue <span style="color:red">*</span>
      </label>
      <label style="width:1%;float:left;">:</label>
      <label style="width:20%;float:left;">
        <textarea cols="80" id="event_venue" style="width:77% !important;" name="event_venue" rows="10">
          <?php if(isset($restaurant_edit_data[ 'rest_description'])) echo $restaurant_edit_data[ 'rest_description'];?>
        </textarea>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      CKEDITOR.replace('event_venue', {
        width: "630",
      });
    </script>
    <p style="clear:both;"></p>
    <p>
      <label style="width:20%;float:left;">Event Description <span style="color:red">*</span>
      </label>
      <label style="width:1%;float:left;">:</label>
      <label style="width:20%;float:left;">
        <textarea cols="80" id="event_desc" style="width:77% !important;" name="event_desc" rows="10">
          <?php if(isset($restaurant_edit_data[ 'rest_description'])) echo $restaurant_edit_data[ 'rest_description'];?>
        </textarea>
    </p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      CKEDITOR.replace('event_desc', {
        width: "630",
      });
    </script>

  </fieldset>
  <div class="clear"></div>
  <p>
    <label style="width:20%;float:left;">&nbsp;</label>
    <label style="width:1%;float:left;">&nbsp;</label>
    <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    <input class="button" type="button" value="Cancel" name="cancel" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us your controller code, so we can see how you're trying to get the file.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find problem, because in my computer everything works fine, but can explain you method debug:

1) Remove from your code any fragment that is not connected with problem:

I created `index.html` with this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta lang="en">
</head>
<body>

<form action="test.php" method="post" name="addform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <fieldset>

        <hr>

        <p>
            <label style="width:20%;float:left;">Event Image</label>
            <label style="width:1%;float:left;">:</label>
            <input type="file" name="event_image" id="event_image" onchange="checkExtension(this.value)" />
        </p>
        <p style="clear:both;"></p>
        <hr>


    </fieldset>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <p>
        <label style="width:20%;float:left;">&nbsp;</label>
        <label style="width:1%;float:left;">&nbsp;</label>
        <input class="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        <input class="button" type="button" value="Cancel" name="cancel" onclick="javascript:history.go(-1);" />
    </p>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Next I created file `test.php` in the same directory with content:

```
<?php

var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
```

After connecting file in form I obtained the following content:

```
array(1) { ["submit"]=> string(6) "Submit" } array(1) { ["event_image"]=> array(5) { ["name"]=> string(38) "image.png" ["type"]=> string(9) "image/png" ["tmp_name"]=> string(14) "/tmp/phpBQAZXv" ["error"]=> int(0) ["size"]=> int(124622) } }
```

Show me your result of this test. Probably problem is in processing, not in form.

Comment: this is my controller function   public function add_event()
  {
   $post_data = $this->input->post();
   print_r($post_data);
  }

Comment: And its printing all data except image        Array ( [event_title] => Event 1 [age] => 15 [event_date] => 20 nov 2016 [event_time] => 10 am [event_venue] =>

Pune
[event_desc] =>

Dummy
[submit] => Submit )

Comment: So you found solution. Files are in $_FILES, but you handle only $_POST. Please try my exemplary code to see what is going on. Let print_r on $_FILES

Answer (score 0):

Create a function in Your Controller by the name of add_event because your are posting your form data to this action. your code may like below

```
class adminpanel extands CI_Controller{

function add_event(){
 echo $_FILES['event_image']['name'];
}



}
```